# Thumbnail position + size

Tags: thumbnails

Good afternoon,

I'm currently having a home page with a header and a footer. I would like to show the last posts there with a thumbnail plus an excerpt under it.

The thing here is that I want to positionate the thumbnails and define their size as well, beign able to put them wherever I want in the backend, thtough, for example, a select field.

Example:

Size: 1,2,3,4,5 = 500px,600px,700p

Position: 1,2,3,4,5 =margin-left:0, margin-left:20%...*

I heard about Advanced Custom Fields plugin but I don't know wich is the best way to do that.

Thanks so much in advance.